# Choose file to upload - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I'm trying to automate a system that will update rates and upload them automatically. So far, I've managed the following:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim ie As Object

website = "https://www.citycurrencyexchange.co.uk/control/login.php?accesscheck=%2Fcontrol%2Findex.php"

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie

    .Visible = True
    .navigate website
    .resizable = True

End With

While ie.readyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
On Error Resume Next

ie.document.getElementById("username").Value = username
ie.document.getElementById("password").Value = password
ie.document.getElementById("button").Click

While ie.readyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

website = "https://www.citycurrencyexchange.co.uk/control/ratescsv.php"
ie.navigate website
While ie.readyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
```

I'm stuck at the point it requests me to upload a file:

[image: Screenshot]

The file to be uploaded is a csv file based on our network with the path - \192.168.10.200\Data\Xenox\Rates (Xenox)\Rates\Victoria (TEG)+City Currency Exchange\ExchangeRates.csv

Is this at all possible or would it require human input?

Also, the code written above won't function as the username and password has been replaced. Was pasted above for reference.

Below is the HTML code relating to the "Choose File" button.

```
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" id="uploadedfile" accept="application/csv" onchange="checkFileName();">
```

Many thanks.

Comment: You can't use automation to assign a file to a "file" upload element - for understandable security reasons.  You may be able to find a way using sendkeys or the Windows API

Comment: Can you type straight into the field? If not, then, what happens when you click on `Choose File` button?

Comment: There's no text field, when clicking the button it gives a chrome pop up to select the file